# Register accuracy?

Tags: typography

I want to have a precise register accuracy in a twosided document.
Unfortunately there will be some graphics in the text.

For a precise register the height of a graphic and the space above and
below it in sum have to be a multiple of the line height.

How to force LaTeX to add space around the graphic which is flexible to
achive a precise register?

Comment: It looks like what you are after is [tag:grid-typesetting]. Depending on the text, it can be very hard to do in TeX (more precisely; e.g., inline maths with lots of height/depth).

Comment: There are »[grid](http://ctan.org/pkg/grid)« and »[gridset](http://ctan.org/pkg/gridset)«. But both won't do the job perfectly.